# Using Altorouter along with .htpasswd basic authentication

Tags: php, api, rest, altorouter

My index.php

```
require_once 'altorouter.php';
$router = new Router();

$router->map('GET', '/', function() {
    require 'home.php';
}, 'home');

$router->map('GET|POST', '/dashboard/[*:serial]?', function($serial) {
    require 'dashboard.php';
}, 'dashboard');

$match = $router->match();

if (is_array($match)) {

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
        
}

else {

    header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Please check validity of methods and URL slugs.', 'debug' => ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

}
```

The Apache sites-available ssl conf file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            #AllowOverride All
            #Require all granted
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Restricted Content"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

        ServerName example.com
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Autorouter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# Enable last slash in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

When Basic Auth is enabled home.php is accessible (after login), but dashboard.php is not.

```
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Restricted Content"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
        </Directory>
```

`https://www.example.com/dashboard/abcd123/` returns 404

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

When Basic Auth is disabled, everything works fine.

```
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

`https://www.example.com/dashboard/abcd123/` returns 200 and the page.

Is there a way to combine Altorouter with Basic Auth? Why is the '/' route not affected by the authentication, but other routes are?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `AllowOverride All` needs to be enabled. Now the routing works.